# PHP -convert one column in 2D array into 1D array specfying column name

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2D array , which holds the result of a mysql query. here is my code

```
$res=$ $this->dbconnection->Query($Query);
$query_result= array();
while($colRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res))     
{
    $query_result[]= $colRow;
}
```

Now i want 1D array which contains all rows under a particular column in  $query_result.
For example, the database table contains the fields Name and ID,I know , `$query_result[]= $colRow['Name']` will give query results into ID. But  I need all rows under Name and Id separately , such as `$name= $query_result['Name']`,`$Id= $query_result['ID']`. 
Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Didnt clear, not well formatted.

Comment: @Nucleo1985, I need to take all rows under a particular column in a 2D array by array key name instead of specifying  arrayindex

Comment: You need `$name=$query_result['Name'];`. `$name` should be a array?? or it should contain single name?? coz if it is an array then `$query_result` will be 2D array AND not then we need to store all names as single concatenated strings in `$query_result['Name']`

Comment: $name is array for storing all names

Comment: @Sherin Now try my answer, for any error comment on that. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since PHP 5.5.0 you can use...

```
$myfield_arr = array_column($query_result, 'myfield_name');
```

... to isolate a column from a two dimensional array.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 1):

Please try maybe

```
 $res=$ $this->dbconnection->Query($Query);
 $query_result= array();
 while($colRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res))       
 {
    if (empty($query_result))
       $query_result = $colRow;
    else
    {
       foreach ($colRow as $key=> $val)
         $query_result[$key][] = $val;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

After clarifying question in comments with you, solution is:

```
while($colRow=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    foreach ($colRow as $key => $value) {
         if(!isset($query_result[$key])) $query_result[$key]=array();
         $query_result[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting array of rows into array of columns:

```
<?php
$arr2dm = [['key1' => 'val11', 'key2' => 'val21'], ['key1' => 'val12', 'key2' => 'val22']];
foreach ($arr2dm as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $res[$k][] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/514050d07f9ed599e010ccd11e51fc18e39647fa